# Upgrading next.js 12 to next.js 13 with custom fastify server

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-app-beta

I have one application with next.js 12 after upgrading to next.js 13, In app folder all the registerd plugins in fasitfy side are not available. Anybody has come acrross this issue?